# Gruntfile with grunt-contrib-watch, browserify, and hbsfy (handlebars) - Automate transform

Tags: gruntjs, npm, handlebars.js, browserify, grunt-contrib-watch

I pretty new to most all of these tools (grunt, browserify, handlebars). I setup `gruntfile.js` to watch for saves on a few .js files and then run the default browserify bundle command on them automatically. Here is my current `gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('node_modules/grunt/package.json'),
    watch: {
      js: {
        files: ['tvguide.js', 'responsive-tables.js'],
        tasks: ['browserify']
      }
    },
    browserify: {
      js: {
        src: ['responsive-tables.js','tvguide.js'],
        dest: 'bundle.js'
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-handlebars');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch', 'browserify']);
};
```

This works just fine - though maybe the files and src are redundant. However, I got to the point in fleshing out my app where I want to use handlebars for templating and many Google searches for browserify with handlebars led me to this npm package [hbsfy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/hbsfy). The instructions say I would just run `browserify -t hbsfy myscriptusingatemplate.js > bundle.js`I would like to have this command run automatically when I save specific `.js` files but I am not sure how to use both `-o` and `-t` on the same or different files.

I made some attempts using an options object but nothing came of it. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use hbsfy from Grunt, use some config like this:

```
browserify: {
    js: {
        src: ['responsive-tables.js','tvguide.js','tmpl/**/*.handlebars'],
        dest: 'bundle.js'
    },
    options: {
        transform: ['hbsfy']
    }
}
```

This way, you don't need to use grunt-contrib-handlebars at all.

Also, I would suggest not using grunt-contrib-watch, but instead setting the 'watch' option to browserify to true.

Comment: For many reasons this complains that it can't parse my template but issuing browserify from the command line works. I guess there is some convention that the plugin does not follow...